# How do I color all Regex.Matches in RichTextBox

Tags: c#, regex, wpf, richtextbox

So I'm trying to color all the Regex Matches ("tags") in my RichTextBox. I have written this code:

MatchCollection mac;

```
    private void RichTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (RichTextBox.IsFocused)
        {
            if (new TextRange(RichTextBox.Document.ContentStart, RichTextBox.Document.ContentEnd).Text != null)
            {
                // get all tags 
                mac = Regex.Matches(new TextRange(RichTextBox.Document.ContentStart, RichTextBox.Document.ContentEnd).Text, @"\<(.+?)\>");
                //change the color of tags
                this.Title = mac.OfType<Match>().Select(r => colorer(r)).Count().ToString() + " Was found I colored";
            }
        }

    }
    int w = 1;
    private Match colorer(Match ma)
    {


        TextPointer start = new TextRange(RichTextBox.Document.ContentStart, RichTextBox.Document.ContentEnd).Start.GetPositionAtOffset(ma.Index);
        TextPointer end = start.GetPositionAtOffset(ma.Length);

        TextRange te = new TextRange(start, end);

        te.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.ForegroundProperty, new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red));



        list1.Items.Add(ma.Value + ":" + ma.Index + " : " + ma.Length + " teksti: " + te.Text + " : " + (ma.Length + ma.Index));
        RichTextBox.Selection.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.ForegroundProperty, new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black));

        return ma;

    }
```

And this get's the first tag correctly colored, but all the other tags are colored wrong

[image], could anyone help me to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that each highlight of a `TextRange` creates a new `Run` internally in order to change the font color of the span. That means tags are added to the content of the document. Therefore the indices of the matches are no longer valid as the text positions have shifted.

You could add the offset of the inserted tags by multiplying tag length with match index, but this is very error prone, especially when user is allowed to format text.

In general your solution is worst one can come up with as the performance is very bad.
You are applying a regular expression at high rates. But instead od compiling the `Regex` and reuse it you always create a new object. You should reuse asingle `Regex` instance:

```
private Regex ReusableRegex { get; } = new Regex("<(.+?)>", RegexOptions.Compiled);
```

But the main issue is that you are matching the *complete* input against the pattern on every keystroke. Over and over again. Even previously matched ranges get evaluated again and a new `TextRange` is created once more and the `Foreground` is set again, forcing re-rendering of the `RichTextBox`. I don't know your document sizes, but this can get very bad quite fast. `RichTextBox` is already heavy enough.

You should only evaluate the current input.

The following example only checks for the presence of the delimiters. The algorithm ignores the content. Once the start delimiter '<' was found, the algorithm waits for the closing delimiter '>' in order to find a valid token.
You can improve on this e.g. by applying rules to the content of the actual token or detect text deletion e.g. removal of a delimiter.
This is far more efficient then using regex and scanning and formatting the complete document on every keystroke. You can try it.

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window>
  <Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition />
      <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <RichTextBox TextChanged="RichTextBox_TextChanged" />
    <ListView Grid.Column="1" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=MainWindow}, Path=Results}" />
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ResultsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
  "Results",
  typeof(ObservableCollection<string>),
  typeof(MainWindow),
  new PropertyMetadata(default(ObservableCollection<string>)));

public ObservableCollection<string> Results
{
  get => (ObservableCollection<string>) GetValue(MainWindow.ResultsProperty);
  set => SetValue(MainWindow.ResultsProperty, value);
}

private int TagStartOffset { get; set; }
private int TotalMatchCount { get; set; }

public MainWindow()
{
  this.Results = new ObservableCollection<string>();
}

private void RichTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
  var richTextBox = sender as RichTextBox;
  var changeOffset = e.Changes.ToList().LastOrDefault()?.Offset ?? 0;
  string input = richTextBox.Document
    .ContentStart
    .GetPositionAtOffset(changeOffset, LogicalDirection.Forward)    
    .GetInsertionPosition(LogicalDirection.Forward)
    .GetTextInRun(LogicalDirection.Forward);

  // Check if input could be a tag. If true store offset.
  if (input.StartsWith("<"))
  {
    this.TagStartOffset = changeOffset;
    return;
  }

  // If there was a starting tag found and current input is a closing tag
  // then highlight the range
  if (this.TagStartOffset > -1 && input.StartsWith(">"))
  {
    var matchingTextRanged = 
      new TextRange(
        richTextBox.Document
          .ContentStart
          .GetPositionAtOffset(this.TagStartOffset)
          .GetInsertionPosition(LogicalDirection.Forward),
        richTextBox.Document
          .ContentStart
          .GetPositionAtOffset(changeOffset, LogicalDirection.Forward)
          .GetNextInsertionPosition(LogicalDirection.Forward));

    HighLightTextRange(matchingTextRanged);
    ResetTextColor(richTextBox);
    CreateOverView(matchingTextRanged);

    this.TagStartOffset = -1;
    this.TotalMatchCount++;
  }

  this.Title = $"Found and colored {this.TotalMatchCount} tags";
}

private void HighLightTextRange(TextRange textRange) =>
  textRange.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.ForegroundProperty, new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red));

private void CreateOverView(TextRange textRange) => this.Results.Add(
          $"{matchingTextRanged.Text}: {this.TagStartOffset}: {matchingTextRanged.Text.Length} teksti: {matchingTextRanged.Text}: {matchingTextRanged.Text.Length + this.TagStartOffset}");

private ResetTextColor(RichTextBox richTextBox) => richTextBox.Selection.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.ForegroundProperty, new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black));
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I tried your code and it will not work if the text is pasted .

Comment: It was not clear from your question that you want to highlight pasted text. In this case the negative performance of your approach remains the same. The parsing is more complicated. As I said before in my answer while you highlight a TextRange you modify the content of the document and the text positions are shifting. To solve this you have to inspect the document structure and only access the `Run` elements. You should do this in a handler that handles the `DataObject.Paste` event. And don't use regex for this simple search.

Comment: Right now I don't have time. You can try it on your own first. If you need help you can come back. I can post a solution tomorrow if you like.